# gnome-keyring fails on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu, gnome-keyring

I've installed and specified `gnome-keyring` for use with `git` by following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration. Specfically, I've installed `libgnome-keyring-dev` and performed a `sudo make` from **`/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring`**.

However, when I attempt to push to my repo I get the following error:

```
~ (master) $ git push origin master
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

** (process:6877): CRITICAL **: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

It's worth noting that everything worked fine on Linux Mint 18.1 with KDE, but now it's not working with Kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install the `gnome-keyring` package manually.

```
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```